# VB.NET Application re-sizing by itself?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, font-size

I am having this problem for the first time. I recently bought a Macbook and is now using bootcamp to run Windows 10. Whenever I debug my program, the layout will move away causing something like this. (On the right is the running program)

The project folder is copied from my old asus laptop to this new macbook running bootcamp windows 10. The project was created using the same version of VS as well on the old laptop.

[image]

The above image is when I use the font setting for the form : **Microsoft Sans Serif, 8pt**

And below image is when I use a different size font : **Microsoft Sans Serif, 10pt**
[image]
Why is the debugged application re-sized by itself so much by just adjusting the font size?

Here is my computer(Windows 10) specs if necessary :

- Windows 10 Pro
- Visual Studio 2015 Pro
- Display resolution using 2650 x 1600

Comment: Is the display resolution and dpi the same for each computer?

Comment: @DavidWilson No it is different. Currently using MBP 15. Having some issue with the resolution setting when I first installed win10. Everything is small

Comment: Ah ok - try having a look at this link - http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5990-dpi-scaling-level-displays-change-windows-10-a.html#option2 -I found it useful to use an inch ruler to compare with the the on screen ruler - What I would suggest is measure an inch on the first computer where the program looks ok, and then set the 2nd computer to the same ruler measurement.